# I can't get Flash enabled on Chromium version 42.0.2307.0 (64-bit) running on Windows 8.1 (64-bit)

Tags: flash, chromium

When I go back to youtube, I keep getting the "Adobe Flash Player is required to display some elements on this page" Install plug-in button.

I click on the Problems installing link and a message says, “Adobe Flash Player is already installed, but disabled. Click here for more information.”

I click on the link and I am taken to Flash Player Help / Flash Player with Google Chrome page.  I’ve tried all of the steps listed on the page, but none of them work.

I got to chrome://plugins and Flash isn’t even listed.

Any ideas?

Comment: Chromium is not Chrome. Chrome has Flash built-in, Chromium needs it downloading & keeping up to date.

Comment: @Tetsujin I got Flash installed and Adobe's web site says that it's installed.  I just can't get it to be enabled.  It's not even showing up in my plugins list.

Answer (score 4):

If you use Chromium make sure you have the **PPAPI** version of Flash Player installed.

There are two Versions:

- NPAPI (Firefox)
- PPAPI (Opera, Chromium)

Both versions can be found on the adobe download page: https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/

Comment: This answer solved my problem. Apparently the adobe page gives you the wrong download by default.. I had to click "Need flash player for a different computer?" and pick "Chrome/Opera PPAPI".

Answer (score 4):

The "Adobe Flash Player is already installed, but disabled. Click here for more information.”-message appears to all Chromium-based browsers, ie Chrome, Opera but also Chromium, although it is actually mostly targeted for Chrome which has flash inbuilt.

But you can just click on "Need Flash Player for a different computer?" and select "FP18 for Opera ans Chromium - PPAPI" as Browser.
Install Flash and append a flag to the shortcut launching Chromium:

for 32-bit Chromium

```
--ppapi-flash-path="C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Macromed\Flash\pepflashplayer32_VE_R_S_ION.dll" --ppapi-flash-version="VE.R.S.ION"
```

for 64-bit Chromium:

```
--ppapi-flash-path="C:\Windows\System32\Macromed\Flash\pepflashplayer64_VE_R_S_ION.dll" --ppapi-flash-version="VE.R.S.ION"
```

Get the version from the manifest.json in the same path.

Source, Chromium downloads and further reading:
[chromium.woolyss.com](http://chromium.woolyss.com)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I managed to get it working by starting chromium with these switches:

```
chrome.exe --ppapi-flash-path="c:\Windows\SysWOW64\Macromed\Flash\pepflashplayer32_17_0_0_134.dll" --ppapi-flash-version="17.0.0.134"
```

This page helped me: http://chromium.woolyss.com/#flash